# Access Recent Call List from native app in Swift App

Tags: ios, swift, contacts, addressbook

I want to access the Recent Call list in My Swift app and matched the number that I have in My Code.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No it cannot be done in a iOS app.

Technical Reason:

Recent call lists informations are stored in a sqlite db file deep inside the file structure and Apple prevents any access to that file outside your app sandbox.

You can fetch the contacts and its information by Contacts or Addressbook framework but not its call log related information.

Comment: iPrabu, Thanks For sharing...So Can we add the matching number from address book?

Comment: You can definitely read all the contacts and you can check whether the contact has the phone number in your code. I hope this answers your question